# Fill the object with array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have Model In javascript that I fill this model with value except one of them .

```
var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files[0];

    // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
    if (files.length > 0) {
        data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
    }
    var ResturantSharingViewModel =
   {
       Type: $("#SharingTargetType").val(),
       SharingTitle: $("#SharingTitle").val(),
       content: $("#Content").val(),
       ItemId : $("#ItemId").val(),
       Photos: files[0]
   }
```

The Photo parameter in Model  is undefined .

i want fill the Photo object with array of files

but i do not know how to do it ?

Comment: `Photo` or `Photos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the entire files array, rather than the first index

```
var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files; //remove the index [0]

    // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
    if (files.length > 0) {
        data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
    }
    var ResturantSharingViewModel =
   {
       Type: $("#SharingTargetType").val(),
       SharingTitle: $("#SharingTitle").val(),
       content: $("#Content").val(),
       ItemId : $("#ItemId").val(),
       Photos: files[0]
   }
```